# ffmpeg use of ildct flag in progressive encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding

I've encountered a scenario whereby someone else has configured an ffmpeg encoding command with flags that don't make sense, and I'm having difficulty understanding their purpose.

The command in question is:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel info -y -r 29.97 -start_number 0 -i image_sequence_%4d.png -vcodec dnxhd -vf format=yuv422p10,colorspace=bt709:iall=bt601-6-625:fast=1 -b:v 220M -flags +ildct output.mov
```

I've been struggling to find information on what the addition of `ildct` does to the output in this case. It appears to be influencing the media to perceive it as interlaced, even though it is, in fact, progressive. Using the flag `ildct` seems counterintuitive and unproductive.